# Keras one_hot encoding - what's the point when unicity not guaranteed?

Tags: keras

In the following example the text:

> 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.'

gets the encodings `[5, 9, 8, 7, 9, 1, 5, 3, 8]`.

My code:

[image]

In this way the words '`brown`' and '`dog`' get both the encodings of 8 and '`quick`' and '`jumped`' 9.

What is the point of encoding if unicity is not guaranteed?

https://machinelearningmastery.com/prepare-text-data-deep-learning-keras/
https://keras.io/preprocessing/text/

Comment: Just a note - formatting code as markdown as opposed to png is always easier for people to read/answer on this site.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be bad choice of function names since the `one_hot` function actually is using hashing and is equivalent to `hashing_trick` (with standard settings).

See this issue: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/pull/6887

When I do:

```
from keras.preprocessing.text import one_hot
from keras.preprocessing.text import hashing_trick

text = 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.'
print(one_hot(text, n=9))
print(hashing_trick(text, n=9))
```

I get identical results:

```
[5, 6, 2, 6, 5, 8, 5, 4, 1]
[5, 6, 2, 6, 5, 8, 5, 4, 1]
```

So in case you want to have "real" (unique) one-hot encoded results, you need to resort to some other solution (there is no Keras built-in solution for this in the moment as I believe).

Answer (score 0):

You could think of it as dimensionality reduction, though it would be important to know how and why it put certain things into buckets. I remember reading about Vowpal Wabbit doing a sophisticated version of this ("feature hashing") in order to handle a "terafeature".

https://github.com/VowpalWabbit/vowpal_wabbit/wiki/Feature-Hashing-and-Extraction